# Power BI Desktop and Citrix

Tags: powerbi

Can Power BI Desktop be deployed via Citrix? An internet search shows that this question has been raised a couple of times but no one has provided an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. Please refer this [Documentation](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-microapps/set-up-template-integrations/integrate-power-bi.html).